# Mass rename folders and their files in bash/terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, rename, mv

I am trying to mass rename folders and their respective files by use of the command "mv" but its not going very well, I would like the folders to be renamed into:

```
1/
2/
3/
```

etc.

The files in each folder should in this process also be renamed while keeping their file extension.

```
1.png
2.gif
3.jpg
```

etc

Very thankful for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Better approach with a function rather than recursive calls to the same script.

Here's hoping I got all corner cases. This descends into directories recursively to handle deeply nested directory trees.

Caveat: Because the script takes care to not overwrite existing files, gaps may appear in the numbering in some corner cases -- if there is a file `0.txt` in a directory and the first file that is handled in that directory is a `.txt` file, it will be moved to `1.txt`. This also happens if the first file that is handled is `0.txt`, so running the script twice will change the numbering, and running it again will change it back.

So here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

handle_directory() {
    local counter=0

    for i in *; do
        # if the file is a directory (but not a symlink),
        #  handle it before moving
        if [ -d  "$i" ] && ! [ -h "$i" ]; then
            cd "$i"
            handle_directory
            cd ..
        fi

        # extract suffix
        suffix="${i##*.}"

        if [ "$suffix" != "$i" ]; then
            extension=".$suffix"
        else
            # If there is no filename extension, the counter
            # is the whole filename. Without this, we'd get
            # 0.Makefile and suchlike.
            extension=""
        fi

        # find a filename that isn't already taken
        # this may lead to gaps in the numbering.
        while dest="$counter$extension" && [ -e "$dest" ]; do
            let ++counter
        done

        echo mv "$i" "$dest"
        let ++counter
    done
}

# if a parameter was given, go there to handle it.
# otherwise handle the local directory. 
if ! [ -z "$1" ] && ! cd "$1"; then
    echo "Could not chdir to directory $1"
    exit -1
fi

handle_directory
```

The general idea is a depth-first search of the directory tree in question. Like any tree, the directory tree is best handled recursively, and the function essentially boils down to: Walk through all things in this directory, if they are a directory, descend and handle it, then find an appropriate file name and rename the thing whether it is a directory or not.

Things used:

```
local counter=0 # declares a function-local variable counter and initializes it
                # to 0. crucially, that it is local means that every invocation
                # of handle_directory has its own counter.
[ -d "$i" ]     # tests if "$i" is a directory
[ -h "$i" ]     # tests if "$i" is a symlink
! [ ... ]       # negates the test. ! [ -h "$i" ] is true if "$i" is NOT a symlink
"${i##*.}"      # a bashism that cuts off the longest prefix that matches the pattern
[ -e "$dest" ]  # tests if "$dest" exists
$1              # the first parameter with which the script is called
[ -z "$1" ]     # tests if "$1" is an empty string
! cd "$1"       # descends into the directory "$1". true if that failed.
```

Manpages to read to further understanding:

```
man test
man bash # that's the big one.
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it a single level directory? Or do you have subdirectories?

Something like this?

**Before**:

```
.
├── folderE
│   ├── conf.properties
│   ├── omg.avi
│   └── test-diff.diff
├── folder_a
│   ├── first.png
│   ├── main.jpg
│   └── second.gif
├── folder_d
│   ├── another.zip
│   └── one.mpeg
└── with space
    └── file with spaces too.mov
```

**Command:**

```bash
countDir=1
for dir in *; do
  cd "$dir"; 
  countFile=1

  for file in *; do 
    mv "$file" $countFile.${file#*.}
    ((countFile++))
  done

  cd ..
  mv "$dir" $countDir
  ((countDir++))
done
```

Or, the same in one line:

```bash
countDir=1; for dir in *; do cd "$dir"; countFile=1; for file in *; do mv "$file" $countFile.${file#*.}; ((countFile++)); done; cd ..; mv "$dir" $countDir; ((countDir++)); done
```

**After:**

```
.
├── 1
│   ├── 1.properties
│   ├── 2.avi
│   └── 3.diff
├── 2
│   ├── 1.png
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   └── 3.gif
├── 3
│   ├── 1.zip
│   └── 2.mpeg
└── 4
    └── 1.mov
```

**Important:** keep in mind that this is just a quick and dirty solution and there's no checking for files/directoris already named "1" "2" etc.

Comment: + 1 for a model file-processing question. O.P. Please take note! ;-) Good luck to all.